# How To Make An Intro (Merge 2 Videos) With FFMPEG with sound

Tags: merge, ffmpeg

Hey guys I wanted to ask how can i merge 2 videos or create an intro to a video with ffmpeg. I found many codes but when i put the intro with those codes, all the video becomes soundless because of the intro. I really need that. Thank you for your suggests.

Comment: You need to actually show your `ffmpeg` command and the complete console output.

Comment: This is the ffmpeg command: 

file 'video2.mp4' 
file 'video.mp4'
-f concat -i t.txt -c copy output.mp4

 And here's the end of the console output: (there is more lines anyway, I can show more if needed)

 [mp4 @ 0000000002bd06e0] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 2993
36, current: 299008; changing to 299337. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
frame= 1896 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 Lsize=     254kB time=00:00:31.45 bitrate=  66.1kbits
/s
video:235kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing o
verhead: 7.803856%

 After merge its soundless.

Comment: I meant as an update to your question, not by trying to cram it all into a comment. In addition to your concat command please also show: `ffmpeg -i input1 -i input2`